# What can you put in the {}s in a /give command?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What are the things you can put in the `{}`s in a `/give` command? I know some like `ench` and diplay but no others.

Here are the tags that I know how to use:

```
/give @p leather_boots 1 0 {display:{Name:"Dese Boots Aren't Made For Walking",Lore:["Some Stylish Boots Right Here"]},ench:[{id:0,lvl:15},{id:16,lvl:15}]}
```

That gives me a pair of leather boots with protection XV and sharpness XV Named "Dese Boots Aren't Made For Walking" with Lore of "Some Stylish Boots Right There".

What other tags can you put on items (like potion effects while equipped or attacked with, custom damage, and stuff like that)?

Comment: If you want armour to add a potion effect, check out [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/210372/how-do-i-get-armor-to-add-a-potion-effect)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: Specifically, see the section about NBT.

Answer (score 2):

The `{}` part of the give command is the data tag or NBT data of the item. A full list of valid NBT tags for all items is quite extensive and subject to change with every version/snapshot. I will give a brief overview instead, and refer to the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format#Item_structure) for a full list. Basically, the data tag can include anything listed as a subtag of

> **tag**: Additional information about the item, discussed in the below sections. This tag is optional for most items.

This includes:

- Enchantments (`ench`)
- Potion effects
- The `display` tag, with things like color, name and lore
- Tags for written books
- `BlockEntityData`, holding NBT data of things that have data when placed in the world, such as chests (this alone is a large topic)
- ...

Note that while you can put a lot of things as data, the game simply ignites everything that makes no sense to it. Putting an `author` tag on a sword it's no different from putting a `banana` tag, neither do anything but waste memory.